# How to do offline data backup of an Ionic 2 app (user data is stored using Couchbase Light)?

Tags: ionic2, backup, couchbase-lite, android-database

I am a beginner and developing an app using Cordova, ionic2 and Couchbase Lite for user data storage. I want the app to work offline. The app should be able to back up the data stored in the Couchbase Lite database to a specific location in the mobile itself. Suggestion or an example code that performs this task helps me a lot.

Comment: check out [Storage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/) you can also use the native [SQLite plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/) i think it allows for larger storage.

Comment: Sync option is available with Couchbase Light. That is the reason for selecting it. If possible please provide some code example.

Comment: Cordova is related to PhoneGap.  You can find a lot of information on the Couchbase site.  There's also this Github repo: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin And you can find blog posts about using Ionic with Couchbase at https://blog.couchbase.com/